# How to import modules from a separate directory?

Tags: python-3.x, asyncore

I want to import asyncore from a different directory, because I need to make some changes to how asyncore works, and don't want to modify the base file.

I could include it in the folder with my script, but after putting all the modules I need there it ends up getting rather cluttered.

**I'm well aware of making a sub directory and putting a blank __init__.py file in it. This doesn't work.** I'm not exactly sure what happens, but when I import asyncore from a sub directory, asyncore just plain stops working. Specifically; the connect method doesn't get run at all, even though I'm calling it. Moving asyncore to the main directory and importing it normally removes this problem.

I skimmed down my code significantly, but this still has the same problem:

```
from Modules import asyncore
from Modules import asynchat
from Modules import socket

class runBot(asynchat.async_chat, object):

    def __init__(self):

        asynchat.async_chat.__init__(self)
        self.connect_to_twitch()

    def connect_to_twitch(self):

        self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.connect(('irc.chat.twitch.tv',6667))
        self.set_terminator('\n')
        self.buffer=[]


    def collect_incoming_data(self, data):  
        self.buffer.append(data)    

    def found_terminator(self):
        msg = ''.join(self.buffer)
        print(msg)


if __name__ == '__main__':  


    # Assign bots to channels
    bot = runBot()

    # Start bots
    asyncore.loop(0.001)
```

I'm sure this is something really simple I'm overlooking, but I'm just not able to figure this out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing files from different folder in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder-in-python) Make sure to look at the second answer.

Comment: Oh come on. I SPECIFICALLY said that using an __init__.py file won't work. The first answer should work, although it's not very pretty. I'd appreciate an alternative if one exists, or an explanation as to why asyncore doesn't work properly when imported through a subfolder with __init__.py in it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sys.path.append` -- see https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html for the details.

*Update:* Try to put a debug print to the beginning and end of sources of your modules to see whether they are imported as expected. You can also print `__file__` attribute for the module/object that you want to use to see, whether you imported what you expected -- like:

```
import re
#...
print(re.__file__)
```

Comment: Actually, you'd use sys.path.insert(0,path). Using append would make it so it would be the last place checked, whereas I need it to be the first place checked. Otherwise my modified asyncore would never be found. Also, this is a bit hacky. This is what I've been using, but I'd really like a prettier alternative if it exists.

Comment: I agree. It depends on situation. See the Update above.